# RGBDslam:negative mahalanobis distance

Tags: slam, navigation, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I try to use rgbdslam for my dataset consisting out of depth and rgb images saved as png.

To make my live easy I tried to write a bag file from these images and then use this bagfile for the rgbdslam. But when I start the reconstruction I get a error about a negative mahalanobis distance and absolut nothing gets reconstructed.

What could be the cause for that? How can even a negative mahalanobis distance emerge?

here is a sample output:

```
[ERROR] [1359413304.934807938]: Non-Positive Mahalanobis Distance for vectors 2.68921e+22
1.42928e+22
6.56501e+22
1
and
1.08665e-31
7.1891e-32
2.5584e-31
1 with covariances
6.56972e+17           0           0
          0 7.03062e+17           0
          0           0 3.23245e+43
and
2.56023e-36           0           0
          0 2.73984e-36           0
          0           0 4.90904e-64
[ERROR] [1359413304.935060057]: Non-Positive Mahalanobis Distance for vectors -4.749e-39
-3.48146e-39
-1.29024e-38
1
and
7.44725e-30
6.38305e-30
1.98261e-29
1 with covariances
-1.29116e-43            0            0
           0 -1.38174e-43            0
           0            0  1.24853e-78
and
1.98404e-34           0           0
          0 2.12323e-34           0
          0           0 2.94807e-60
[ERROR] [1359413304.935230189]: Non-Positive Mahalanobis Distance for vectors -2.44741e+27
1.18307e+27
4.70933e+27
1
and
-6.61237e-31
3.8003e-31
1.30072e-30
1 with covariances
4.71271e+22           0           0
          0 5.04332e+22           0
          0           0 1.66333e+53
and
1.30165e-35           0           0
          0 1.39297e-35           0
          0           0 1.26891e-62
```

## EDIT 1:

I think the problem lies in the saving and re-conversion to a sensor_msgs of the depth map. My self-written bag file is displayed totally different as the original bag file.
I uploaded some Images to explain the problem a little bit better to imgur.com [here](https://imgur.com/a/WBalN)

There are three screenshots. In every screenshot is the RGBDslam gui plus the window from image_view dispalying the same depth map.
When I playback the original reference bag file everything works and the image_view and the RGBDslam display of the depth map are identical.
When I playback my own bag file these two are significantly different.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53423/rgbdslam:negative-mahalanobis-distance/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could happen for NaN depth values (the error message should be "non-positive", not "negative").
These are ignored in the ransac inlier determination, so it should be no problem.

From the output you added, it's obvious that the depth values are completely wrong. Unfortunately I do not know how to correct them.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2013-01-28**:
please sse the edit. When I start the reconstruction nothing gets reconstructed. The vectors seems to me way to small or big...

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2013-01-31**:
did you see my upoaded pictures?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-02-04**:
Yes, but I don't know how to correct them. I know nothing of that factor 5000. Rgbdslam assumes float values in meter, and I guess that is what it gets in the first picture.